# How to query database from javascript (or JQuery) click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a summary view of a database table. When clicking on a row in the table, I'd like to have a popup showing the full data plus some controls for manipulating that item. I've attached a click handler to the  item, which then grabs the primary key from one of the table cells in the row. How can I now pass this primary key to ASP.NET and run server code to query my database and update my UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the click handler, you need to make a call to an exposed page `/somepage.aspx?id={yourid}` which should return the HTML blob that you want to render within the popup you've created.

You can use the [JQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method to do this for you, taking the html generated by your page and transferring it to your popup in one line.

```
$('#your-popup-id').load('database-summary.aspx?id=1');
```

There are other methods, where your page or generic handler can return JSON, which you then parse after making the callback, but this is not the way I would go if you're just starting out.

If you want help with the popup itself, then you can use a library like [qTip2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#ajax) which has built in Ajax > Popup methods, making the task even easier.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using jQuery, you probably want to use the [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or [`jQuery.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) functions to make ajax calls to your backend server which can then return data from your database.

You can then use that returned data to construct the popup and insert the popup into your page to show it to the user.

Answer (score 1):

This question is very broad, so I'll keep my answer pretty general.  The basic idea is that you want to make an AJAX call from your page to your server, include the key in that call, and then when the AJAX call returns use the response to update your UI.